# AngularJS issue in ng-click inside ng-repeat, passing string variable with single quotes

Tags: angularjs

I am facing an issue in angularjs, I need to pass the {{item.Key}} in single quotes, value of item.Key is for example "Blue Color" set in ng-repeat, so single quotes are required by selectMoreFacets() function. When the page is loaded first time, only search bar is visible, user enters a keyword in search, hits enter, then following code ng-repeat is run. When the page is loaded first time, I get the following error in Console because of this maybe

```
{{'\''+item.Key+'\''}}
```

But after hitting search, page is loaded fine, if I inspect element on the

```
<a ng-click="selectMoreFacets('by_Options', optionShowMore?'more':'less', 'Color Temp')"
   class="ng-binding">more...</a>
```

which seems fine and should work when I click the `<a` tag. But its not working, when I click

```
 <a tag , selectMoreFacets()
```

function is not being called and no error is thrown.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in aggsOptions | limitTo:100:3" ng-hide="isLoading">
    <h4><u>{{item.Key}}</u></h4>
    <ul class="category-list">
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.Aggregations.Values.Items" ng-hide="isLoading">
            <span ng-class="{'label-primary label': isActive_Options(item.Key,subItem.Key)}">
                <a ng-click="toggleFilters_Options(item.Key,subItem.Key)">{{subItem.Key}}</a>
            </span><small class="pull-right">({{subItem.DocCount | number : fractionSize}})</small>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a ng-click="selectMoreFacets('by_Options', optionShowMore?'more':'less', {{'\''+item.Key+'\''}})">{{optionShowMore?"more...":"less"}}</a>
</div>
```

Error in console window.

> Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=63&p3=selectMoreFacets(by_Options%2C%20optionShowMore%3F'more'%3A'less'%2C%20%7B%7B'%5C''%2Bitem.Key%2B'%5C''%7D%7D&p4=%7B'%5C''%2Bitem.Key%2B'%5C''%7D%7D>
>
> ````
> at http://localhost:53694/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:416
> at s.throwError (http://localhost:53694/Scripts/angular.min.js:210:32)
> at s.object (http://localhost:53694/Scripts/angular.min.js:209:327)
> at s.primary (http://localhost:53694/Scripts/angular.min.js:206:335)
> at s.unary (http://localhost:53694/Scripts/angular.min.js:206:174)
> at s.multiplicative (http://localhost:53694/Scripts/angular.min.js:205:434)
> at s.additive (http://localhost:53694/Scripts/angular.min.js:205:261)
> at s.relational (http://localhost:53694/Scripts/angular.min.js:205:96)
> at s.equality (http://localhost:53694/Scripts/angular.min.js:204:425)
> at s.logicalAND (http://localhost:53694/Scripts/angular.min.js:204:278) <a ng- click="selectMoreFacets('by_Options', optionShowMore?'more':'less', {{'\''+item.Key+'\''}})">```
> ````

Comment: If I replace {{'\''+item.Key+'\''}} with 'Color Temp' static value, then it works fine. <a ng- click="selectMoreFacets('by_Options', optionShowMore?'more':'less', {{'\''+item.Key+'\''}})">

Comment: I don't know, why are you passing params like this. Use below

<a ng-click="selectMoreFacets('by_Options', (optionShowMore ? 'more' : 'less'), item.Key)">{{optionShowMore?"more...":"less"}}</a>

Comment: I am appending single quotes to the string value resolved by {{item.key}}, but I should have just used item.key.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of brackets and quotes. Just pass `item.Key` :

```
<a ng-click="selectMoreFacets('by_Options', optionShowMore?'more':'less', item.Key)">{{optionShowMore?"more...":"less"}}</a>
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: Its working now, thank you for helping out.